# Perl IO::Socket - Cannot determine peer address

Tags: perl

I am having an issue stemming from IO/Socket.pm on or around line 251.

```
    croak 'send: Cannot determine peer address'
     unless($peer);
```

Basically we are opening a connection up, and sending data to it.  For some reason after 10-20 seconds this error gets thrown.

> send: Cannot determine peer address

Any ideas??

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

package Dialer;

use Data::Dumper;
use IO::Socket;

$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => '255.255.255.255',
                                 PeerPort => '5038',
                                 Proto    => 'tcp');

$res = $sock->send("Action: Login\r\nUsername: dunzo\r\nSecret: 123456789\r\nEvents: \r\n\r\n");
sleep(5);


while(1==1) {
        $res = $sock->send("Action: Originate\r\nChannel: Local/123123@dunzodial\r\nExten: 123123\r\nContext: dunzo\r\nTimeout: 60000\r\nVariable: \r\nAsync: yes\r\nCallerID:               
1234567890\r\nPriority: 1\r\n\r\n");
        $incr++;
        sleep(1);
        print $incr."\n";
}
```

Comment: TCP or UDP? Connected (PeerAddr in constructor) or not? what arguments do you pass to `send`?

Comment: please, could you paste your script (the relevant parts, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => '255.255.255.255',
                             PeerPort => '5038',
                             Proto    => 'tcp');
```

For TCP protocol, `255.255.255.255` isn't a valid unicast IP address. In this case, IO::Socket::INET treat `255.255.255.255` as a domain name. It will request the IP address by query your DNS server with host name `255.255.255.255`. Obviously there isn't such a record, the DNS query operation will be timeout. That's why you got error after 10~20 seconds.